# Trouble Subscribing to Instagram Media Updates via Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to set up a webhook to receive notifications for new media posts (like photos or videos) on an Instagram Business Account using the Facebook Graph API
Here's the process I followed:

I confirmed that the Instagram account is a Business Account and is linked to a Facebook Page.
I ensured that the Page Access Token has the necessary permissions (instagram_basic, pages_show_list, pages_read_engagement).
I attempted to subscribe to the media object updates using the following POST request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/${page.id}/subscribed_apps?subscribed_fields=${page_subscriptions}&access_token=${page.access_token}
```

However, I'm not receiving any response from this request with parameter page_subscription=media – no success confirmation, but also no error message.
I may have selected the wrong page_subscription. I would be grateful for any tips